# Boost bind with a member function causes a compilation error

Tags: c++, c, boost, bind

I've got this working C program:

```
// callback
void NewEIT(void *priv, dvbpsi_handle h_dvbpsi,
            uint8_t table_id, uint16_t extension) {
    // ...
}

void Decoder::open_file()
{
    dvbpsi_eit = dvbpsi_AttachDemux(NewEIT, NULL);
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to "convert" it in C++:

```
void Decoder::NewEIT(void *priv, dvbpsi_handle h_dvbpsi,
            uint8_t table_id, uint16_t extension) {
    // ...
}

void Decoder::open_file()
{
    dvbpsi_eit = dvbpsi_AttachDemux(boost::bind(&Decoder::NewEIT, this), NULL);
    // ...
}
```

I'm new to boost::bind, so I'm trying to do what I've found in the doc and here in stack overflow, but I cannot get rid of this error: **No matching function for call to 'dvbpsi_AttachDemux**.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong in my C++ code ? Thanks !

Here the definition of dvbpsi_AttachDemux:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * dvbpsi_AttachDemux
 *****************************************************************************/
/*!
 * \fn dvbpsi_handle_t dvbpsi_NewPSISection(dvbpsi_demux_new_cb_t pf_new_cb, void * p_new_cb_data)
 * \brief Creates a new demux structure.
 * \param pf_new_cb A callcack called when a new type of subtable is found.
 * \param p_new_cb_data Data given to the previous callback.
 * \return a handle to the new demux structure.
 */
__attribute__((deprecated))
dvbpsi_handle dvbpsi_AttachDemux(dvbpsi_demux_new_cb_t pf_new_cb,
                                 void *                p_new_cb_data);
```

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem; `dvbpsi_AttachDemux` can only accept an `extern "C"` callback, so if you want to use `boost::bind` you'll need to write an `extern "C"` adaptor.

Comment: Thanks ecatmur, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `dvbpsi_demux_new_cb_t pf_new_cb` is exactly, but your `boost::bind` call does not what you believe it does.

Like it is it will produce a `function` object that takes no parameter. If you do want to get the four parameters passed through you'd probably want to go with:

```
boost::bind(&Decoder::NewEIT, this, _1, _2, _3, _4)
```

I'd say that you need to adapt the `dvbpsi_demux_new_cb_t pf_new_cb` in order to accept a `function<void(void*, dvbpsi_handle, uint8_t, uint16_t)>`, or if you can not modify that code, write an `extern "C"` adaptor, like @ecatmur mentioned in his comment.

The `extern "C"` adaptor would simply wrap the C++ code into a C function:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void NewEIT(void *priv, dvbpsi_handle h_dvbpsi,
        uint8_t table_id, uint16_t extension);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and in the source file:

```
Decoder d;

void NewEIT(void *priv, dvbpsi_handle h_dvbpsi,
        uint8_t table_id, uint16_t extension)
{
    d.NewEIT(priv, h_dvbpsi, table_id, extension);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot modify dvbpsi, so I think I have to write an extern "C" adaptor, but what does it mean ?

Comment: @CirrusMinor I am going to eat, when I come back I'll give an example!

Comment: Thanks Theolodis, it works this way. And I don't need boost binding anymore. You've helped me a lot !